# Rails | Migration missing | Works locally but not on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

This is my first Stackoverflow post, so please let me know if I can specify my problem any better than I am: I've searched the site and haven't found anything that fixed my problem.

I have an app running locally with an **Event** model.

The model has a **start_date** column and I later added an **end_date** with a migration.

Everything works locally.

When I deploy it to Heroku I get an **500**-error when trying to create an *Event* entry.

It first gave me an *ActiveRecord::MultiparameterAssignmentErrors*, saying that it couldn't assign anything to end_date=.

I looked through everything and made sure that it was a permitted parameter.

Then I looked through my migrations and found to my surprise that my *AddEndDateToEvents* migration didn't exist, but the *end_date* column is in my schema model.

So I ran a *rails g migration AddEndDateToEvents* where I wrote:

```
class AddEndDateToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_column :events, :end_date
    add_column :events, :end_date, :date
  end
end
```

I ran *rails db:migrate* and everything works locally.

Now when I push it to Heroke and I run *db:migrate* there as well, it of course terminates and tells me that it cannot remove the column *end_date* because it doesn't exist in the model.

I'm stuck. What shall I do? :(

References of my source code

- GitHub: https://github.com/Curting/mydanceplan
- Heroku: https://mydanceplan.herokuapp.com/

Thank you in advance!

Oliver

Comment: Where did the `end_date` column in your local database come from? Presumably, from an earlier migration? If so, why doesn't that migration exist on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it with your help, Mark! :-)

I did the following:

**1) Roll back migrations**

I ran `rails db:migrate:status` and saw that I should roll back two migrations to get completely clean of my attempts to add/remove the end_date column.

When I tried to rollback, it gave me an error that my remove column migrations weren't reversible. I had to enter the type of column. So I added that as a third parameter. Example: `remove_column :events, :end_date, :date`

After that a rollback was possible. The easiest way was to run *rails db:rollback STEP=2*.

**2) Delete down migrations and check schema**

After rolling back my migrations, I deleted the unneeded migration-files from the folder. Also, I checked my schema file and manually removed the end_date row from the model.

**3) Create conditional remove row migration**

Using Mark's answer, I added a new migration with the following code:

```
class AddEndDateToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_column(:events, :end_date) if column_exists?(:events, :end_date)
    add_column :events, :end_date, :date
  end
end
```

**4) Reset database and run db:migrate**

I then did my *git push && git push heroku* and then I ran `heroku restart && heroku pg:reset DATABASE --confirm APP-NAME && heroku run rake db:migrate`, where APP-NAME was the name of my app.

And now it works! :-)

Thank you very much. I'm quite blown away by the quick and helpful response, and the fact that some person out there on the interwebs took the time to edit my post and format it nicely.

Generous community. Nice!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your migrations are out of sync as you say. The best way to cover both bases is to add a conditional into the migration. Rails comes with a method called column_exists?

https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/column_exists%3F

Which we can use in our migration:

```
class AddEndDateToEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    remove_column(:events, :end_date) if column_exists?(:events, :end_date)
    add_column :events, :end_date, :date
  end
end
```

That should now work whether or not the initial migration has been run

EDIT: It probably is best to keep both your databases in sync, so if your Heroku DB has no important data in it, you can always simply drop it, recreate it and run all migrations from the start. I think that's preferable if you can afford to lose whatever data is in your Heroku DB

Comment: "add a conditional into the migration"—this sends a shiver down my spine. IMO a much better (though more painful) solution is to manually fix whichever database is in the wrong shape, bringing both into sync. This should match the `schema.rb` file and also the cumulative result of running all migrations. Then, once there's a consistent and stable base, write a new migration from there.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! :-)
I ran a pg:reset on Heroku and the flushed DB didn't work. There are no migrations that indicates the added end_date column. So from the looks of it, the Heroku build is the "correct" one and somehow my local one is off. I have the feeling that if I run a db:reset locally, then I would get the same bug here.

So I'm going to try with your column_exists? solution, since it sounds like a good fit :-)